# Send data with pushwoosh in a notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I configure my ios application with pushwoosh SDK and its really simple and work fine.
Now i want to send for example an `id` of a product to show when push i received or any think else but user have no to see this data. i try `page` but dont work to.

Q1 : how can i do it ?.
Q2 : what is this `page` ?.

Edit: i just found the documentation of Rich pushes ( `page` ) : [link](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/advanced-form-tutorial/) , i send a push notification with title=test and a `page` witch contain an href to google , but in `onPushReceived: withNotification: onStart:` function this is the description of dictionary of the received push:

```
{
aps =     {
    alert = test;
    sound = default;
};
h = 774;
p = x;
}
```

as i see, the 774 is the id of the page send in the push message, ok i can use that but how can i get the content of that page ( a web service ? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send your Custom Data through Remote API request. Currently you cannot do that via the web form.

As for Remote API, it's pretty simple. See the guide on this:

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-Method%2Fmessages%2Fcreate

Comment: 'Page' is an HTML push notification, some call it Rich Push. You can create and send rich formatted messages, that includes links, images, webforms, etc.